# Db2 high availability Instance configuration db2haicu fails

Tags: db2, high-availability

Hi I Configured db2 HADR between two servers and the servers are running in HADR Primary and Standby are syncing up

I tried to configure the instance configuration utility db2haicu on both the servers

when i tried to run the db2haicu i get the Following log Errors

```
2014-07-20-21.56.27.547634+330 E5186198E907          LEVEL: Error
PID     : 21580                TID : 47378715596352  PROC : db2haicu
INSTANCE: db2inst1             NODE : 000
HOSTNAME: testServer213.int.in.nmc.domain.se
FUNCTION: <0>, <0>, <0>, probe:2467
RETCODE : ECF=0x90000544=-1879046844=ECF_SQLHA_CREATE_CLUSTER_FAILED
  Create cluster failed
DATA #1 : String, 61 bytes
libsqlha: sqlhaCreateDomain() call error from wrapper libra ry
DATA #2 : String, 394 bytes
Line # : 15864---2632-044 The domain cannot be created due to the following errors   that were detected while harvesting information from the target nodes:
testServer265: 2610-441 Permission is denied to access the resource class specified in this command.
Network Identity UNAUTHENT requires 's' permission for the resource class IBM.PeerDomain on node testServer265.int.in.nmc.domain.se.
; FFDC ID:
DATA #3 : signed integer, 4 bytes
```

21

Comment: You may not have run `prepnode` on testServer265. More info at http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/tutorials/dm-1009db2hadr/index.html?ca=drs

Comment: i ran preprpnode on both the servers as root user